# Should I use both NotNull and ContractAnnotation("null => halt")?

Tags: null, resharper, static-analysis, design-by-contract

It seems that `NotNull` and `ContractAnnotation("key: null => halt")` are fairly similar in their effect on R#. Is there something that I am missing? Should I always apply both?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They're very similar, but are semantically very different.

`NotNull` states that the target is expected to not be null, but makes no statements about the consequences. There might be a null check that throws an `ArgumentNullException`, or it might just use it without checking, and you could get a runtime `NullReferenceException`. Equally, the application might check for null, log it and continue safely.

`ContractAnnotation("key: null => halt")` tells ReSharper that if the `key` parameter is null, then the program flow terminates. ReSharper can use this like so:

```
string foo = null;
Assert.NotNull(foo);  // ContractAnnotation("null => halt")
Assert.Equal(12, foo.length);
```

The second assert in this snippet will be marked as dead code, because ReSharper knows the first assert will throw when passed a null.

However, if `Assert.NotNull` was just marked with the `NotNull` attribute, then ReSharper would highlight the `foo` parameter with a warning, telling you that you shouldn't be passing a null value, but it doesn't know what will happen if you do.

Subtle, but different. I'd stick to the `NotNull` attribute if you require the value to never be null, and use `ContractAnnotation("null => halt")` for an assert style method that will definitely and explicitly throw if passed a null.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Still feels a bit wrong having to write null-checking/-annotating code thrice: the contract, the NotNull annotation and then the runtime guard.

Comment: My question was inspired by Microsoft's EF7 code. It seems that they are using contracts only for their guards class, and NotNull + guards for everything else:

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Data.Entity/Utilities/Check.cs

Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @Den oh wow, that annotations code looks straight [out of my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546556/can-i-tag-a-c-sharp-function-as-this-function-does-not-enumerate-the-ienumerabl/23552374#23552374) :) That's so cool!

Comment: @IgalTabachnik: I have seen your answer before :). I couldn't make my implementation any better then yours/their version. Do you have any idea why MS guys did not use JetBrains annotations throughout all their code?

Comment: I wouldn't regard it as writing it 3 ways. You write it once, then use an annotation to provide edit-time analysis of what you've done. If you write a null check, use `ContractAnnotation` to say you'll throw if it fails. If you don't, use `NotNull` to say you're assuming it's not null, without an explicit check.

Answer (score 5):

In short:

- Normally you should only use `[NotNull]`/`[CanBeNull]` annotations. They are validated by R# to notify if you are breaking contract. They are propagating through interface implementation and virtual method overrides. They are easy to understand.
- You can use `[ContractAnnotation]` if you need to be more expressive on specifying how method behaves. It is not a replacement of `[NotNull]`/`[CanBeNull]`. It allows you to link method inputs and outputs, link `notnull`/`null`/`true`/`false` values, specify inputs that will make you method `halt`. The string you are passing to `[ContractAnnotation]` called "function definition table", this is just an abstraction over method body behavior.

Typically need to use `[ContractAnnotation]` when `[NotNull]`/`[CanBeNull]` is not enough expressive in cases like:

```
if (!IsNotNullAndAlsoValid(obj)) return; // null => false

Assert.That(x != null); // false => halt

if (!map.TryGetValue(key, out value)) { // => false, value: null
  ...                                   // + key parameter annotated as [NotNull]
}
```

And yes, `[NotNull]` is semantically different from `[ContractAnnotation("null => halt")]`. This is easy to illustrate in the code, sometimes R# knows for sure that execution will halt because of NRE and highlight remaining code as 'dead':

```
C c = null;
c.InstanceMethod(); // possible NRE
c.SomethingElse();  // unreachable code
```

But when you are using `[NotNull]`-annotated APIs, R# just warns you about 'Possible NRE'. This is done because in the case R# has not enough information about some value being not null, it shouldn't highlight the rest of the methods as potentially unreachable:

```
C c = AlwaysTrue ? new C() : null;
Util.NotNullAnnotatedMethod(c); // possible NRE
Util.OtherMethod(c);            // no warnings here
if (c != null) { ... }          // no warnings here
```

While `[ContractAnnotation]` allows you to specify behavior more strictly, so that R# will rely on annotation more aggressively:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) return; // text: null => false
if (text != null) { ... }               // condition always true
else { ... }                            // unreachable code
```